# Vertex deviation of the velocity ellipsoid

Tags: astrophysics, eigenvalue, galaxies, structure-formation

### Context

I will be working here in [galactic coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system). This system uses distance from the Sun $(r)$, longitude $(l)$ and latitude $(b)$. The latter two are angles defined as shown in the following figure, where "Center" is the centre of the galaxy:

[image]

The following treatment will be restricted to the galactic plane. In the study of galaxy dynamics, the distribution of stars in $v_r-v_l$ space, where $v_r$ and $v_l$ are the radial and longitudinal velocities respectively, is usually called the *velocity ellipsoid*. See eg [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13905).

The velocity ellipsoid is best described using the covariance matrix, defined as
$$C = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{rr}^2 & \sigma_{rl}^2 \\
\sigma_{lr}^2 & \sigma_{ll}^2 
\end{pmatrix},$$
where the diagonal elements are the variances of the radial and longitudinal velocities (eg $\sigma_{rr}^2=\langle v_r^2 \rangle - \langle v_r \rangle ^2$). The term $\sigma_{rl}^2$ is the covariance between the two, given by $\sigma_{rl}^2=\langle v_rv_l \rangle - \langle v_r \rangle \langle v_l \rangle$. We can see $\sigma_{rl}^2 = \sigma_{lr}^2$ and hence the covariance matrix is symmetric.

The covariance matrix can be thought of as a linear transformation composed of a scaling and a rotation, which would transform white noise into the distribution at hand. Finding the eigenvector of the covariance matrix with the largest eigenvalue gives you the direction of the semi-major axis of the velocity ellipsoid. This is the direction of greatest dispersion of the data. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23596/) math stackexchange question. The following figure illustrates a dataset example:

[image]

Each red dot in this plot is a star, located in $v_r-v_l$ space. We can see the distribution has a downward trend, which is related to a negative value of the covariance. I have drawn the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix as  and . The direction of  is that of the largest variance of the data. The eigenvalue, $\alpha$, associated to this eigenvector is the spread in that direction.

### Problem

In the literature, a quantity which is often used is the **vertex deviation**, $\theta_v$, defined as:
$$ \theta_v = \frac{1}{2}\textrm{arctan}\left(\frac{2\sigma_{rl}^2}{|\sigma_{rr}^2-\sigma_{ll}^2|}\right).$$
This is said to be the angle that the major axis of the velocity ellipsoid makes with the radial, aka line-of-sight, direction. See for example [Vorobyov 2007](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2966.2007.12476.x) or [Debattista 2019](https://doi.org/10.1093/mnras/stz746).

I interpret this as the angle I have drawn in green in the figure. That is, the angle between the major axis of the velocity ellipsoid and the $v_r$ axis. This could be wrong, but I can't think of any other way of interpreting it.

I have tried finding a derivation of the equation in the literature, but I have not been able to. The [Vorobyov 2007](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2966.2007.12476.x) paper points to page 630 of the [Galactic Astronomy](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691025650/galactic-astronomy) 1998 book by Binney & Merrifield. I have not been able to access that page unfortunately, and the book is quite expensive. If someone could send me a picture I would really appreciate it.

### My attempt

Assuming my interpretation of vertex deviation is right, from the figure above we can see it is given by
$$\theta_v = \textrm{arctan}\left(\frac{a_l}{a_r} \right),$$
where $a_r$ and $a_l$ are the radial and longitudinal components of the eigenvector of $C$ with the largest eigenvalue. Hence I want to find what this ratio $a_l/a_r$ is.

The eigenvalue problem is
$$C=\alpha,$$
which can be re-written as
$$(C-\alpha I) = \mathbf{0}.$$
To find the non-trivial solution, I need det$(C-\alpha I)=0$, which is
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\sigma_{rr}^2-\alpha & \sigma_{rl}^2 \\
\sigma_{rl}^2 & \sigma_{ll}^2 -\alpha
\end{vmatrix} = (\sigma_{rr}^2-\alpha)(\sigma_{ll}^2 - \alpha) - \sigma_{rl}^4 = 0.
$$
This can be solved as
$$\alpha = \frac{\sigma_{rr}^2+\sigma_{ll}^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(\sigma_{rr}^2+\sigma_{ll}^2)^2 - 4 (\sigma_{rr}^2\sigma_{ll}^2-\sigma_{rl}^4)},$$
where I have chosen the + solution since I am after the largest eigenvalue.
The above can be re-written as
$$\alpha = \frac{\sigma_{rr}^2+\sigma_{ll}^2}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_{rr}^2-\sigma_{ll}^2}{2}\right)^2 + \sigma_{rl}^4}.$$
Coming back to the eigenvalue problem, I have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{rr}^2 & \sigma_{rl}^2 \\
\sigma_{rl}^2 & \sigma_{ll}^2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a_r \\ a_l \end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix} a_r \\ a_l \end{pmatrix},
$$
which is the system of equations
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{rr}^2 a_r + \sigma_{rl}^2 a_l \\
\sigma_{rl}^2 a_r + \sigma_{ll}^2 a_l
\end{pmatrix}
= \alpha \begin{pmatrix} a_r \\ a_l \end{pmatrix}.
$$
I will work with the first equation, which can be written as
$$a_l = a_r \left( \frac{\alpha - \sigma_{rr}^2}{\sigma_{rl}^2} \right).$$
Expressing $\alpha$ in its fully-fledged form and after some manipulation I get
$$\frac{a_l}{a_r} = \frac{\sigma_{ll}^2-\sigma_{rr}^2}{2\sigma_{rl}^2} \left(1+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2\sigma_{rl}^2}{\sigma_{ll}^2-\sigma_{rr}^2} \right)^2} \right).$$

Therefore, my expression for vertex deviation is
$$\theta_v = \textrm{arctan}\left[\frac{\sigma_{ll}^2-\sigma_{rr}^2}{2\sigma_{rl}^2} \left(1+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2\sigma_{rl}^2}{\sigma_{ll}^2-\sigma_{rr}^2} \right)^2}\right)\right],$$
which differs from the standard
$$\theta_v^\star = \frac{1}{2}\textrm{arctan}\left(\frac{2\sigma_{rl}^2}{|\sigma_{rr}^2-\sigma_{ll}^2|}\right).$$

Any help, corrections or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to derive the equation used in the literature. I wrote the method out in [this math stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286925/). The absolute value of the dispersion difference is something that some researchers take by choice (since they are not interested in which dispersion dominates, just in the strength of the ellipse's tilt with respect to the axes).